# Creating a pdf with multiple pages per sheet

Tags: puppeteer-sharp

Is there a simple way to create pdfs with multiple pages per sheet using PuppeteerSharp (as per the option available when you print a pdf from Chrome) e.g. 1 / 2 / 4 / 6 / 9 / 16 pages per sheet?

Comment: That's not part of the DevTools protocol :/ https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-printToPDF

Comment: Thanks - I'd checked the docs but wondered whether there was an easy way to do this within PuppeteerSharp.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick that I created where the viewport is set to a certain width and height, and then the container div of the page is set to the "contained" height after trial and error.

**pdf generation function**

```cs
public async Task<byte[]> GeneratePDF(string html)
{
    var browser = await GetBrowserAsync();
    var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
    // Here, we sit the viewport height to match a div height in html
    await page.SetViewportAsync(new ViewPortOptions{Width = 720, Height = 1280 });
    await page.SetContentAsync(html);
    var data = await page.PdfDataAsync(new PdfOptions
    {
        PrintBackground = true,
        Format = PaperFormat.A4,
        DisplayHeaderFooter = false,
        MarginOptions = new MarginOptions
        {
            Top = "60px",
            Right = "40px",
            Bottom = "60px",
            Left = "40px"
        }
    });
    return data;
}

private async Task<IBrowser> GetBrowserAsync()
{
    var browserOptions = new BrowserFetcherOptions{ Path = AppContext.BaseDirectory };
    using var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher(browserOptions);
    await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision);
    string[] args = {"--no-sandbox"};
    var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
    {
        Headless = true,
        Args = args
    });
    return browser;
}
```

Razor page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <style>
    :root {
        --primary-color: #ffffff;
        --accent-color: #f2f2f2;
        --secondary-color: #5f7cb3;
        --text-color: #000;
    }
    body {
        font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        color: var(--secondary-color);
    }
    .page-height {
        min-height: 870px; /*trial and error*/
        height: 870px;
        max-height: 870px;
        padding: 30px 0;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-height" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,BASE64_HERE" alt="logo.png" style="width: auto; height: 80px; padding: 20px 0;"/>
        <h2 style="color: var(--text-color);">Title Here/h2>
        <h3>Subtitle Here</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="page-height">
        <p>Content of the first page.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="page-height">
        <p>Content of the second page. Etc...</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This should do the trick.